# CSS background position move as page resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I move the background position of the image so it stays between 2 elements as the page resizes?

I managed to get it working for the first one with some Javascript but that same function doesn't work for the second one.

This is what I'm getting. [Here's the link](http://tonyle.co.uk/test/).

The bottom leaf moves too much and I need it to stay between the cat and text

This is the Javascript I've got for the first leaf.

```
function bgPos(){
    var w = $(window).width() - $('.container').width();
    w = w*2;
    $('.class2').css('background-position', w+'px 0')
}
$(window).on('resize', bgPos).trigger('resize');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Once you remove that website how can this question and it's answers be helpful to anyone? Please read [ask]

Comment: i cant seem to replicate this on js fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/h40h2mdm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bgPos function fort .class2 should look very similar to bgPos function which you use for class1, but with with a horizontal delta (I've used value 500)

```
var w = $(window).width() - $('.container').width();
w = w/2-500;
$('.class2').css('background-position', w+'px 0')
```

This delta is a distance that should be kept between these "green" leaps on resize. You could find better value to keep it sharply perfect